# BIG query syntax issue?

Tags: google-bigquery

```sql
WITH longest_used_bike AS (
  SELECT
    bikeid,
    SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` 
  GROUP BY 
    bikeid
  ORDER BY
    trip_duration DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: This lacks any question or description of the issue (such as the error message).

Answer (score 1):

As we see, you are using a CTE approach...
**Common table expressions (CTEs)** help you break up complex queries in BigQuery.
Here's a simple to illustrate how to write a CTE:
**In your case:**

```
-- Your query is ok but didn't use 
WITH longest_used_bike AS ( 
      SELECT bikeid,
      SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration 
      FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
      GROUP BY bikeid ORDER BY trip_duration DESC LIMIT 1 )
-- continue to use it for example:

select * from longest_used_bike

-- Note that you should execute all queries above at once!
```

**More examples that can help you to understand the CTE concept:**

```
WITH unique_users AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT username
FROM logins),
 
min_logged AS (
    SELECT  username,
            DATEDIFF (minute, login_start, login_end) AS minutes
FROM logins)
 
SELECT  u.username,
        AVG (minutes) AS avg_time_logged
FROM uniqe_users AS u
JOIN min_logged AS m
ON u.username = m.username
GROUP BY u.username;
```

You can find more standard SQL details about CTE in this :
[guide](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/)

Comment: You can also practice with these BigQuery CTE examples [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/common-table-expressions-5-tips-for-data-scientists-to-write-better-sql-bf3547dcde3e)

Answer (score 0):

You added a `WITH` clause without actually using it anywhere. The `WITH` clause is used to emulate a temporary table name that you can use in a query afterward. For example

```
with table2 as (Select column1,column2 from table1)
    select column1 from table2
```

Use `longest_used_bike` or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Javier. With clause is redundant here.

Since your query is single block and does not need any temp view. You can write as follows as :

```
SELECT bikeid, 
       SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration 
FROM bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips 
GROUP BY bikeid 
ORDER BY trip_duration DESC 
LIMIT 1
```